# Why does alt+shift change language for all applications in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language, input-languages

In Windows 7, if there are two opened application, when one is focused and you press alt+shift it changes language for that application. Then after focus is switch to another application the language is automatically changes back to default unless you press alt+shift for that one too. But in Windows 8 when press alt+shift it changes language for all application.

Is there any way to change this behavior in Windows 8 to act like in Windows 7?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open Control Panel, go to Language item, then press "Advanced Settings" link, and then mark checkbox "Let me set a different input method for each app window" under "Switching input methods" section. 
Then your Language switching will be exactly like in Windows 7.