# Language changing in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, input-languages, regional-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why in Windows 8 alt+shift change language for all applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/515221/why-in-windows-8-altshift-change-language-for-all-applications)

This is a bit hard to explain. I'll try my best:  I have two languages enabled in my windows. EN and FA.

In **Windows 7** I could work with a program (e.g. Microsoft word), changed the language to `FA` with <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, maybe type something and then switch to another program like Google chrome with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and see my keyboard language changes back to its default value (`EN`) automatically . This was actually very neat for someone like me who wanted to work with certain programs in one language and with other programs in English without having to do any manual language-changing.

But in **Windows 8**, this is not the case. When I change the language and switch between programs, nothing happens. I have to manually change my language very frequently.

Is there a way that I can change this behavior?

Comment: ... I have a feeling that what happened was that a bunch of users for Win7 complained, saying "Hey, whenever I switch programs, it reverts back to the default language.  Microsoft Sucks!".  Personally, I'd agree with what you're experiencing in Win8 - the setting should stick around until explicitly changed.

Comment: Shouldn't be *that* hard/unreasonable to make this an option for the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why in Windows 8 alt+shift change language for all applications?](http://superuser.com/q/515221/80304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to open Settings search.
2. Type `methods`.
3. Click or tap **Change input methods**.
   [image: Change input methods in Settings, results for “methods”]
   Language Control panel will open.
4. Click or tap **Advanced settings** on the left pane.
   [image: Language Control panel in Windows 8]
5. Select **Let me set a different input method for each app window** check box.
   [image: Language Advanced settings in Windows 8]
6. Click or tap **Save**.

Now language switching will work the way it used to work in previous versions of Windows.

<sub>Alternative way: click language icon on the Taskbar, and the click **Language preferences**. Follow steps 4 further from above.</sub>

Comment: You just made my day!