# Input method editor changes globally - in Windows 7 it was per app

Tags: windows-10, ime

I might be wrong, but I seem to remember that any switching of Input method editors ([IMEs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/input-method-editors)) in Windows 7 affected only the application I was working in at the time, whereas switching to a different IME in Windows 10 affects all apps.

I have not seen options to control that and Google also does not offer much for this topic - is that behavior unavoidable or is there a setting somewhere to have it change just in the foreground-app?

Comment: The solution is the same as in [Language changing in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/537442/language-changing-in-windows-8).

Comment: T H A N K   Y O U so much! It's just a little well-hidden checkbox, but that has been one painful change in the transition from 7 to 10. If you post this as answer, there's a bounty waiting! ;-)   (It's silly, but I learned on SO that simple link-replies will automatically be converted into comments - so you'll have to add a bit content to it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open `Control Panel`
2. Click on `Clock, Language, and Region`
3. Click on `Add a language`
4. Click on `Advanced settings` (left sidebar)
5. Activate checkbox `Let me set a different input method for each app window`